# Code builds successfully but crashes out

Tags: c

I can print `*p` with `printf("%d",p[1])` but I can't print `**p` with  `printf("%d",p[1][1]`.
I tried to write a function that allocates memory and assign its adress to  the element(**members) of struct. But I still can't print it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int **members;
    int line; //number of lines
    int clmn; //number of columns
}matrix;

void mamal(matrix matrix1) //function to allocate memory  
{

    int ** m; 
    m=(int**)calloc(matrix1.clmn,sizeof(int*));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<(matrix1.clmn);i++)
    {
        m[i]=(int*)calloc(matrix1.line,sizeof(int));
    }
    matrix1.members=m; // allocated memroy assigned to struct elemnt
}

int main (int argc,const char * argv[] ){

matrix matrx1;

printf("Enter Column:");        //Reading struct elements
scanf("%d",&matrx1.clmn);       //Reading struct elements

printf("Enter Line:");          //Reading struct elements
scanf("%d",&matrx1.line);       //Reading struct elements

mamal(matrx1);  
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<matrx1.clnm;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<matrx1.line;j++)
    {
        printf("[%d][%d]:%d",(i+1),(j+1),matrx1.members[i][j]); //This line causes crash I think. I can't print memory block that **pointer points.
    }
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that arguments in C are passed *by value*. Which means they are *copied*, and modifying a copy will not modify the original. Do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: And about your terminology, I think you mean to say that it *builds* successfully, because the crashes happens when you *run* your program.

Comment: Oh and a last thing, you allocate a matrix of `clmn X line`, not a matrix of `line X clmn` which you use in the `main` function. If `clmn != line` then you will still allocate the same amount of memory, but it will not be in the layout you expect, possibly leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if you happen to out of bounds.

Comment: I think, he is a newbie on C. He may have some problems like this. But we can help him anyway. I understand that you are building your code, but can not run it or having some trouble when you run it.